# Not able to use H2O to interpolate a function

Tags: r, h2o

I am new with H2O and I am trying to use it, as initial test, to train a Neural network to interpolate a function.
I am trying with several, but no one works!!!
I get a NN which does not match the training set. I also tried by rescaling data (not here attached for simplicity), but it does not change.
Here is my code:

```
x<- seq(-50, 50, by=0.01)
y1<- x
f1<-data.frame(x, y1)
f1.hex<-as.h2o(f1)
random.vec <- h2o.runif(f1.hex)
train <- f1.hex[random.vec < 0.6, ]
valid <- f1.hex[(random.vec > 0.6) && (random.vec < 0.8),]
test <- f1.hex[random.vec > 0.8, ]


  m1 <- h2o.deeplearning(
  training_frame=train, 
  validation_frame=valid,   
  x=1,
  y=2,
  activation="RectifierWithDropout",   ## default
  hidden=c(25,25),             
  epochs=100,
  input_dropout_ratio = 0,
  hidden_dropout_ratios = c(0.5, 0.5), 
  stopping_rounds = 5,
  stopping_metric = "AUTO", 
  stopping_tolerance = 0.001  
  )

plot(m1, timestep = "duration", metric = "deviance")  
summary(m1)
pred <- h2o.predict(m1, f1.hex[,1])
pred.r<- as.data.frame(pred)
```

I get a wrong predicition with a huge deviance...
Altro tried to cheange epochs and other parameters...
Where am I wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same horrible results. The easy fix was to stop using dropouts. So my code became:

```
m2 <- h2o.deeplearning(
training_frame=train, 
validation_frame=valid,   
x=1,
y=2,
activation="Rectifier",
hidden=c(25,25),             
epochs=100
)
```

This doesn't give perfect results, but much better.

Why? Dropouts are a way to deal with noisy data. Your data is the polar opposite of noisy. If using dropouts you normally have to give more hidden nodes, and more epochs, to compensate.

Going back to your linear function, H2O was only doing two scoring events, one at 10 epochs, one at 100 epochs. So, curious to see how epochs helped, I took manual control of when scoring happens: after every 5 epochs here. (I recommend against this for real work, but for kicking the tyres of H2O with artificial data sets like this, it can be educational.)

```
m3 <- h2o.deeplearning(
training_frame=train, 
validation_frame=valid,   
x=1,
y=2,
activation="Rectifier",
hidden=c(25,25),             
epochs=500,
train_samples_per_iteration = 50005, score_each_iteration=TRUE
)
```

The scoring history chart (from Flow) then looks like:

[image]

Early stopping kicked in at 143 epochs.